# Group or find associations and orderings for elements that appear in different samples (analyzing examples of input files for undocumented code)

Tags: sampling, association-rules

I'm trying to understand and use a physics simulation code that was written decades ago. It uses input files that have their origins in stacks of [punch cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card) as input. In other words each line is a card.

The number of users has always been small and so no information exists that we would call proper documentation in the 21st century.

I have a collection of example input files (or 'stacks') and they are all composed primarily of parameter assignments

```
x = 7
y  = 42
a = 2.7
z = [sqrt(7)*a, a, 3*a]
w = 3D
```

Some assignments occur in most or all files, *but many others occur only in some or just a few files.*

It also looks like they often occur in groups, for example if I see that w is set to '3D' then there will always be a z set to a list of three items.

If I call all the symbols on the left hand sides of the assignments "parameters" (e.g. x, y, a, z, w) I'd like to do a statistical analysis of these input files to see

1. How often is each parameter is used?
2. which parameter clusters always appear together; or at least which parameters only appear when another parameter is present?
3. In what order do parameters tend to appear? (I don't know if order matters for the software (not sure yet) but if one item always appears just before another, it will at least indicate something about the thinking of the input file authors.)

This seems like something for which a standard methodology might exist, and if I am lucky, for which a Python package that implements the methodology also exists, though I can certainly write a script to implement a methodology if it can be articulated.

Comment: I'm a bit of a fish out of water here; help with tagging is appreciated!